# mod_rewrite URL to a deep link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, deep-linking, swfaddress

I was wondering if this was possible in mod_rewrite, and if anyone knows the syntax for it.

Browser receives:

http://example.com/video/my-first-vid/

mod_rewrite redirects to:

http://example.com/#/video/my-first-vid/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't use mod_rewrite for redirecting to **/#/video/my-first-vid/** as the # sign is urlencoded and it will redirect to http://example.com/%23/video/my-first-vid/ which obviously isn't what you're looking for. I tested this couple of days before on Apache 1.3.

You may create a separate script(s) for redirection. Add a new rules for this:

```
RewriteRule ^video/?$ /redirector.php?page=video [NC,L,QSA]    
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$ /redirector.php?page=video&subpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But you might also need to parse the query string manually as it could be smth like:

```
/video/my-first-vid/?refID=test
```

Here's some simple example on PHP:

```
<?php
  $page = (isset($_REQUEST["page"])) ? trim($_REQUEST["page"]) : "";
  $subPage = (isset($_REQUEST["subpage"])) ? trim($_REQUEST["subpage"]) : "";

  // setting the redirect URL, your conditions here
  if ($page == "video") 
  {
    $url = "/#/video/" . $subPage;
  } 
  else
  {
    $url = "/"; // some default url
  }

  header("Location: " . $url);
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's a great example. I did however stumble across a method which seems to work `RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /#/$1/$2/ [NE,R,L] ` - it takes **mydomain.com/video/video1** to **mydomain/#/video/video1** I think the flags allow the hash(#) to pass through. Could this cause any SEO problems do you think?

Comment: @JCraine The [NE] flag (no URI escaping of output) after the modrewrite rule actually solves the problem. So one doesn't need to bother with my previous solution, just add one flag :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about embedding the '#' in the URI, since that's typically a fragment identifier, but you could try this:

```
RewriteRule "^(?<!#/)(.*)" "#/$1" [R=301,L]
```

That should redirect anything that *doesn't* have a '/#' in front of it to the same location *with* '/#' in front of it.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me, however I did get some good results with the following: RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /#/$1/$2/ [NE,R,L]

Comment: @JCraine Yeah, I missed the `.htaccess` tag.  I've modified the answer appropriately.

Comment: So with friendly URLS, if you've specified a link; mysite/video/ to go to mysite.com/video?id=20 the search engine will pick up the first url right?